# How to use multiple user inputs in a function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have difficulty in writing an algortihm that takes three numbers as input from the user and calculates the maximum of them. I'm trying to do these by using function, however, I get an error message: "Undefined function 'calc' for input arguments of type 'char'.

> Error in Untitled (line 2)  calc(numbers); "

Here's my code: (I'm new at coding so there may be other types of errors:))

```
numbers= input('Enter three numbers to find out maximum of them:','s');
 calc(numbers);
 maxi

function [ maxi ] = calc( numbers(1),numbers(2),numbers(3) )
%UNTİTLED2 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

maxi= numbers(1);

if numbers(2)>maxi
        maxi= numbers(2)
end

if numbers(3)>maxi
        maxi= numbers(3)
end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

As you say that "I'm new at coding", I thought I'd describe a couple of different approaches for this.

**Reading the input**

1. You could do as *H.Ghassami* suggests and read the input one by one.
   This is probably the better option as there is some fault handling
   built into it. The user can only enter one input at a time and there
   is check that the inputs is evaluable (a number or a variable from
   the current workspace). The rutin could get a little bit more general by adding a variable for the number of inputs to get.

   ```
   numberOfInputs  = 3;
   number = zeros(1, numberOfInputs);
   for idx = 1:numberOfInputs
       % Get the number of inputs declared in numberOfInputs  
       number(idx) = input( sprintf('Enter number %d: ', idx));
   end
   ```
2. You could also let the user enter all the numbers at once by, as the example in your question, add a 2nd argument 's' to `input`. The input is now treated  as a string. The user has to separate the input numbers in some way, preferable with a whitespace. You then have to convert to string to a number vector.

   ```
   numberOfInputs  = 3;
   number = input( sprintf('Enter %d numbers separated by whitespaces\n', numberOfInputs), 's');
   number = str2num(number); % Convert to number array
   ```

   You should probably do some check on the number array to see that it is valid (numbers of the correct amount)

**Getting the max**

Matlab has an buildin function for this. So you could just write

```
maxNumber= max(number);
```

or if you, perhaps for the exercise, would like to use an `if` structure you could make it more general with a `for` loop

```
maxNumber = number(1);
for idx = 2:numberOfInputs
    if maxNumber < number(idx)
        maxNumber = number(idx);
    end
end
```

-

The entire solution could be encapsulated in a function

```
function maxNumber = getMaxInput(numberOfInputs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first mistake is `input` . It just get just one string from user, but you need three numbers.
Second one is the next line in your script. When you calculate the numbers, you should send output to a variable. Also you should change the `calc` parameters.

Put this code in your script instead of your code :

```
number1= input('Enter number1:');
number2= input('Enter number2:');
number3= input('Enter number3:');
 maxi=calc(number1,number2,number3)
%---------------------------------------------------  
function [ maxi ] = calc( numbers1,numbers2,numbers3 )
%UNTİTLED2 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

maxi= numbers1;

if numbers2>maxi
        maxi= numbers2;
end

if numbers3>maxi
        maxi= numbers3;
end

end
```

refrence to read for you: http://matlabgeeks.com/tips-tutorials/getting-user-input/

Comment: It helped me a lot :). Thanks

Comment: check the tick if it is your answer plz